# Spring bind a bean to rest post request

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have following REST service build around Spring. I want to implement a POST method which can add user. The data for user is in request body and can be either in JSON/XML. I want server side implementation

1. to automatically map incoming data to Java bean
2. and handle both type of data (JSON/XML) using single implementation.

I have tried with `@ModelAttribute` in `addUser` method of `UserController` but getting all fields empty in `user` object. Any clue?

Here is Spring configuration file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rest.sg.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <!-- JSON View -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
            </bean>
            <!--  XML view -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                        <property name="classesToBeBound">
                            <list>
                                <value>com.rest.sg.bean.User</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />

</bean>
```

UserController class and addUser method

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/user")
    @ResponseBody
    public User addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        userService.addUser(user);
        return user;
    }

}
```

And User Bean

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "blahblah")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields
    // Getter , Setters
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller needs to know how to map the data. The default is mapping request parameters on the object's properties.

If you send JSON that represents the `User` object you can try

```
public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
```

Comment: if I use `code`@RequestBody, I receive `code`HTTP Status 415 on client side. Error description is `code`The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

Comment: Does your request have the content-type `application/json` (or `application/xml`)? Do you have Jackson included in your classpath (if your request is JSON)?

Comment: Yes I have Jackson included in the classpath. I am trying with both types i.e. JSON/XML as I want single method to handle both data types (point 2 in my question)

Comment: What `Content-Type` does your client send? And could it be a Multipart request?

Comment: Client can send either JSON or XML. No request cannot be Multipart

Comment: If you get 415 with `@RequestBody` then the content type of the request is not supported by the message converter. That means either Jackson and JAXB are not included or the request has the wrong content type. Can you post the respective part of the request's header?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/persons", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                headers="Accept=*/*", 
                consumes="application/json")
public User addUser( @RequestBody User u){
              //Code.
}
```

When sending request, send the header

```
Content-Type:application/json //This is important
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Actually I want this method to handle both data types i.e. XML/JSON (point 2 in my question). I think that's possible but how?

Comment: You need `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`

    http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html

Comment: I think I am already using `ContentNegotiationViewResolver` but not working properly